# Can we have unity configuration inside PRISM module configuration?

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, unity-container, prism, prism-4

We have a product which acts as a base framework for other applications/teams.

I am declaring type mappings through unity configuration. On the other hand, every configured module has its `IModule` implementation in which we map a view with predefined region.

However, to achieve this, every other 'module' project team has to write its `IModule` implementation and do 'region mapping/registration' themselves in the code.

**Is it somehow possible for every module to tell my base product that it wants to register  X, Y, Z  types/instances through unity "configuration"? My base framework will resolve types/instances and do appropriate mappings. It will allow module teams to focus just on their WPF business views instead of implementing `IModule` etc.**

At present, type mapping is possible in unity but I cannot associate registration with the Prism module. Further, it's not possible to map a resolved type with the predefined region.

E.g. In our application Shell we have a region named 'BusinessRegion'. We have an interface called `IBusinessView`. Every module will have several business views. Depending on module & its workflow, we have to navigate from one business view to another. However, at present I cannot know which business view belongs to which module.

Answer (score 0):

The same question is already answered in the following **CodePlex** forum site:

- [Can we do WPF view-region mapping & interface-type mappings in the configuration?](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/473479)

As commented at **CodePlex's**, there wouldn't be possible to know which **View** belongs to each **Module** after they are initialized. **Views** and components get registered in the **Container** and **Regions**, loosing any dependency reference with the **Module**.

Regards.